# Running Benchmark in GEM5GCN3

Tags: benchmarking, chai, gem5, heterogeneous

I hope you are well
I use GEM5GCN3 simulator.
I work on heterogeneous systems(CPU-GPU) so I have to run benchmarks on GEM5GCN3.
I used heteromark benchmarks and I ran this command:
sudo docker run --rm -v /home/atiyeh/Desktop/Hetero-Mark:/benchmark -v /home/atiyeh/Desktop/data:/mydata -v /home/atiyeh/Desktop/gem5:/gem5 -w /gem5 gem5gcn3 build/GCN3_X86/gem5.opt  configs/example/apu_se.py --benchmark-root=/benchmark -c build/src/aes/cl12/aes_cl12 -o /mydata/aes -i /home/atiyeh/Desktop/data/aes/1MB.data -k **but there was an error with it**
info: Standard input is not a terminal, disabling listeners.
apu_se.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -k /home/atiyeh/Desktop/data/aes/key.data

I ran chai benchmarks too, also it is running but it doesnt show me any result
sudo docker run --rm -v /home/atiyeh/Desktop/chai:/benchmark -v /home/atiyeh/Desktop/gem5:/gem5 -w /gem5 gem5gcn3 build/GCN3_X86/gem5.opt  configs/example/apu_se.py --benchmark-root=/benchmark -c OpenCL-U/CEDT/cedt

so if you had same problem like me or you know what the problem is, would you please help me:((SOS)